# Returning recursive structure from WCF service

Tags: wcf, recursion

I have below data structure to represent the tree

```
public class TreeNode : IEnumerable<TreeNode>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, TreeNode> _children =
                                        new Dictionary<string, TreeNode>();
    public readonly string ID;
    public TreeNode Parent { get; private set; }
    public TreeNode()
    {
        this.ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }
    public void AddChild(TreeNode tNode)
    {
        if (tNode.Parent != null)
        {
            tNode.Parent._children.Remove(tNode.ID);
        }
        tNode.Parent = this;
        this._children.Add(tNode.ID, tNode);
    }
    public IEnumerator<TreeNode> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this._children.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

I am trying to return this tree structure from wcf service.

```
[OperationContract]
TreeNode GetMenuItems();
```

and i get exception saying "Type 'TreeNode' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection 'TreeNode' to remove references to itself."

When i annotated the TreeNode calss with `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]`, exception went away.
But when the treenode is received in the client side its children `_children` property is not coming populated and its always null.

Thanks, 
Mallikarjun

Answer (score 0):

By annotating `_children` with `DataMember` issue got resolved.